# Hereku java spring boot app - version

Tags: java, maven, heroku, build, version

In documentation I read java 8 is default, but I use 9.0.4 version and I dont know where to set system.properties in my app project to push app to hereku to recognize and build my app, still failed from hereku maven building

**You can specify a Java version by adding a file called system.properties to your application.
Set a property java.runtime.version in the file:
java.runtime.version=9**

Comment: are you using the heroku-maven-plugin?

Comment: no Im new about heroku i use only <plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin> I add this and try

Answer (score 0):

In your `system.properties` file in the root of the application repo, you should put:

```
java.runtime.version=9.0.4
```

Then make sure you add it to Git with `git add system.properties` and `git commit`.

Or if you are using the heroku-maven-plugin you can add the following plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <jdkVersion>9</jdkVersion>
</configuration>
```

Comment: with hereku plugin I am suceeded works fine, but if i commit changes and push to hereku it shows in log java 1.8 detected, co I think i have to usesystem.properties too?